# Publish from http://localhost:5555/ to a specific domain name http://localhost/ProjectName/

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, publish

how can I Publish from something like `http://localhost:5555/` to a specific domain name `http://localhost/ProjectName/` please?

May I get some detailed procedures pls?

I am using visual studio 2010, asp.net C#

thanks a lot. =D

Comment: You need to set up IIS site/application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the virtual path to use on localhost in the project properties.

Project Properties > Web > Servers > Virtual Path > Set to value required.

Answer (score 0):

1st option: You could just create a simple directory in your server called "ProjectName", and publish your application there, so you'll can access via `http://localhost/ProjectName/`

2nd option: You could create a virtual directory `/ProjectName` to your application on IIS, I have found 2 great tutorials that show step by step how to do that:

1. http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory
2. https://kentico.atlassian.net/wiki/display/K7I/Creating+virtual+directories+and+application+pools+in+IIS+7.5+and+7.0

Good article to understand about Applications and Virtual Directories in IIS (has also about IIS 6.0)
http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis#About7.0